# How can I solve typeError: $(...).slider is not a function on vue component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, laravel-5.3, vue-component, vuex

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-range">
            <li>
                <span class="text">Min</span>: <span class="price-min">{{ priceMin }}</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="text">Max</span>: <span class="price-max">{{ priceMax }}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <input id="price-range" type="text" style="display: none">
        </div>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        mounted() {
            if ($('#price-range').length) {
                $("#price-range").slider(App.options.slider).on('slide', function (e) {
                    let min = e.value[0],
                        max = e.value[1];
                    ...
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If the vue component run, on the console exist error like this :

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).slider is not a
>   function"

I had load slider library

If I put in the global javascript (main.js), it works

But if I put in the vue component, there exist error like above

How can I solve the error?

**Update** :

I find a solution

```
mounted() {
    $(function(){
        if ($('#price-range').length) {
            $("#price-range").slider(App.options.slider).on('slide', function (e) {
                let min = e.value[0],
                    max = e.value[1];
                ...
            });
        }
    })
}
```

It works

Comment: Have you loaded slider library first and then the Vue files?

Comment: @hamzox, I had find solution